# How to animate "scrollTop()"?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I use this code for fixed header of my page:

jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('scroll resize', function() {
    $('#header').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    position: relative;
}
```

How can I animate `scrollTop()`?

Comment: Try the jQuery Scroll To plugin http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Why don't you just do `position: fixed`?

Comment: @Blender since I'm searching for some effects for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#header').animate({'top' : $(this).scrollTop()});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).bind('scroll resize', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#header').animate({top : $this.scrollTop()});
});
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

It has to be like

```
$('#header').scrollTop(value);
```

atlast

```
$("#header").animate({ scrollTop: "value in px" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$('#header').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#header').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).scrollTop()}, "slow");
```

[**Example Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1363/)